# How to do groupby and then replace values of a column with baseline value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame as follows, which columns are Car#,measurement_type and measurement _value.

```
Car#     measurement_type      measurement_value 
1         back to back1                10.3
1         back to back2                10.2
1         baseline                     10.4
2         back to back1                11.5
2         back to back2                10.8
2         baseline                     10.9
```

I would like to create a new column called (Baseline) in which the values are the baseline value for each car. So the output will look like this:

```
Car#     measurement_type      measurement_value      Baseline
1         back to back1                10.3              10.4
1         back to back2                10.2              10.4  
1         baseline                     10.4              10.4
2         back to back1                11.5              10.9
2         back to back2                10.8              10.9
2         baseline                     10.9              10.9
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
grouped = df.groupby('car#')
for i in grouped:
    if df['measurement_type'] == 'baseline':
        df['Baseline'] = df.loc[df['measurement_type'] == 'baseline','measurement _value']
```

Can someone help please.

Comment: It's pretty hard to read your data in the way it's presented. Please do some formatting to help better visualize. It's also not clear what you're asking for. How does one determine the baseline value for each group?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using [`df.loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and `map()`

```py
Baseline = (df.loc[df["measurement_type"] == "baseline"]
              .groupby("Car#")["measurement_value"].first())
df["Baseline"] = df["Car#"].map(Baseline)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Car# measurement_type  measurement_value  Baseline
0     1    back to back1               10.3      10.4
1     1    back to back2               10.2      10.4
2     1         baseline               10.4      10.4
3     2    back to back1               11.5      10.9
4     2    back to back2               10.8      10.9
5     2         baseline               10.9      10.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other ways:

```
df["Baseline"] = df['Car#'].map(df.loc[df['measurement_type'].eq("baseline"),
                      ['Car#','measurement_value']]
               .set_index('Car#').squeeze())
```

---

```
df["Baseline"] = df['Car#'].map(dict(df.loc[df['measurement_type'].eq("baseline"),
                           ['Car#','measurement_value']]
                    .to_numpy() )
                                )
```

---

```
print(df)

   Car# measurement_type  measurement_value  Baseline
0     1    back to back1               10.3      10.4
1     1    back to back2               10.2      10.4
2     1         baseline               10.4      10.4
3     2    back to back1               11.5      10.9
4     2    back to back2               10.8      10.9
5     2         baseline               10.9      10.9
```

Comment: very efficient ways. thank you so much.